# How to ensure thread synchronization

Tags: iphone, ios, thread-safety, performselector

I have a method `myButtonAction` which performs some heavy calculations, which I need to run  on a background thread, while I am loading a view indicating "Task progress" in the main thread. As soon as the, background thread completes executing the method, I need to remove the "task progress" view and load another view in the main thread.

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myButtonAction) withObject:nil];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

The problem I am facing is that, before `myButtonAction` completes execution, the `LoadView` completes its execution. How can I make sure that `LoadView` starts execution only after `myButtonAction` completes its execution.

Note: `myButtonAction` has its method definition in another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self myButtonAction];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self LoadView];
    });
});
```

Or, if you want to stay with `performSelector` methods:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadViewAfterMyButtonAction) withObject:nil];
```

where

```
- (void)loadViewAfterMyButtonAction
{
    [self myButtonAction];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following -

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myButtonAction) withObject:nil];

- (void)myButtonAction {
    //Perform all the background task

   //Now switch to main thread with all the updated data
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

EDIT - 
Then you can try -

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(buttonActionInBackground) withObject:nil];

 - (void)buttonActionInBackground {
       [self myButtonAction];

       //Now switch to main thread with all the updated data
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
  }
```

Now you don't need to change `myButtonAction`.

Comment: `myButtonAction` is in another class, which I am not supposed to edit.

Comment: @XaviValero - check edited post, and also if you want you can go for GCD.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that this code gets called at the end of myButtonAction:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(LoadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

now no wonder that LoadView finishes before myButtonAction finishes, because you said it to wait until it's done with "waitUntilDone:YES". Call it at the end with waitUntilDone:NO.

For simple solutions to this kind of problems take a look at putting selector calls into the main run loop using `[self performSelector:@selector(sel) withObject:obj afterDelay:0.0]` or NSTimer - for example if you want to wait until UI updates are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I use a [Semaphore Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) for these purposes.

Comment: That's what I call going totally overboard. GCD as suggested in the first answer solves the problem very easily, with basically no effort for the programmer and very little chance of getting it wrong.